# Как программно закрыть Excel при возникновении исключительной ситуации?

Tags: c#, excel, com

```
try
{
    excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
    //Делаем что-то, что вызывает исключение
    //System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
    //При дебаге в этот блок кода заходит, но в процессах 
    //остается висеть EXCEL.EXE
    excelApp.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Народ с английского SO ([см.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024691/1133809))

Рекомендует добавить:

```
excelApp.Application.Quit();
excelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Сделал как указано в Вашей ссылке, все работает. Появляется процесс и вскоре исчезает.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте еще вызвать дополнительно (после Quit):

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
```

Надо также запоминать ссылку на открытую workbook, и аналогичным образом освобождать.

Comment: Хм, так вроде получше. Не накапливаются процессы, висит один-два.
Это, как я понимаю, уже особенности операционной системы и сборщика мусора .NET

Comment: И еще вам нужно сохранять ссылку на workbook, и аналогичным образом ее закрывать. Как правило, если заморачиваются с экселем/вордом и его комами в больших количествах, пишут врапперы, которые реализуют подобное освобождение ресурсов.

Comment: Скорее это особенности COM и RCW-оболочек. Их надо освобождать.

Answer (score 2):

В данном коде создается две временных переменных, которые никто не освобождает:

```
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
```

Нужно освобождать *каждый* объект:

```
var workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
var sheet = workbooks.Open(fileName);
...
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Простой в использовании **костыль** для убивания екселя в любом случае независимо от того освобождал ты обьекты или нет. 100%ное срабатывание.

**Но костыль.**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

private Application _excelApp;

private void CloseExcelApp()
{
    int hWnd = _excelApp.Application.Hwnd;
    uint processID;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)hWnd, out processID);
    Process.GetProcessById((int)processID).Kill();
}
```

**В целом же я советую не работать с ексель файлами через Интерпоп.
Детали почему так найдешь сдесь:**
[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)